# Targeting first 2 children or last 2 children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know a bunch of the pseudo classes (first-child, last-child, nth-child) but I am having trouble selecting the first 2 children in a list or the last 2, the list is dynamic and changes all the time so i cant target based on counting the li's

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code?  Can you add classes to the list?

Comment: Or better yet, you could do this using jQuery.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For the first two children you can use:

```
ul li:nth-child(-n + 2) {
    color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYnSz/1/

For the last two:

```
ul li:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
    color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYnSz/

Comment: Can you explain what the -n does in the selector?

Comment: @Deekey: The fiddle links are there for you to try them out. Try clicking on them.

Comment: n is the element index, which are 1-based (`last` reverses the order). The css will apply to all positive equation results (for which an element is found).